# Accepting untrusted certificates with geckodriver in C#

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, selenium3, geckodriver

I cannot get the code I have to go to the URL without having issues with the certificate. Here is the code I am trying:

```
else if (testMethod.BrowserType.Equals(BrowserType.FireFox))
                {
                    var options = new FirefoxOptions();
                    options.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
                    options.LogLevel = FirefoxDriverLogLevel.Default;
                    options.Profile = new FirefoxProfile { AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true};
                    var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                    _driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
                }
```

I still receive the generic page saying the connection is unsecured, any help on this would be appreciated.

> Webdriver Version: 3.0.0.0
>
> GeckoDriver Version: 0.11.1
>
> Firefox Version: 49.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it should be fixed in the next geckodriver version.
For more details [check here.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1103196)